# Excel 365 is replacing the entire cell rather than the selected text

Tags: excel, excel-365

Not sure why, but my Excel 365 suddenly decided that whenever I use Find & Replace on cells, the entire cells would be replaced with the value specified, rather than the selected text!

For example:

Cell = "xyz"

Find what: "x"

Replace with:"y"

Result = "y"

The above result should be "yyz" rather than "y". Any idea why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: I can only assume that the affected cells contain formulas, and that the replacement is taking place within those formulas (which is the default behaviour), whereas you were expecting it to take place within the cell values.

Comment: Hi Jos, no formulas at all, I literally applied it on the above simple example and this happened. I've been using excel for 10 years and this is the first time this happens to me ... not sure if it's some kind of Microsoft 365 update.